# Javascript / Angular Condition (Rule) evaluation (interpretation)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, conditional-statements, evaluation, rule

I'm trying to interpret/evaluate conditions, which I receive as a string. Example: "active=true^introduction=Mr.^NQdepartmentISEMPTY"

Meaning of the expresssion: (active is true AND introduction is Mr.) OR department is EMPTY

I want to evaluate expressions like this against objects.

I checked out the rule engine part of the following project: https://github.com/chrisjpowers/business-rules

Does someone know, if there is a solution done with angularjs out there? Or any other solutions you know of?

Any input is appreciated :)

Thank you in advance.

Kevin

Comment: use that plugin inside a directive. Need more detail on data source to be able to help more but there are lots of resources on web on how to use jQuery plugins in directives

Comment: What do you mean by data source? An example object that would match the expression could be {"active":"true", "introduction":"Mr.", "deparment":"foo"}